# What makes the enthalpy of hydration of calcium chloride dihydrate unique?

Tags: water, enthalpy, salt

I have recently done an experiment in an attempt to find the relationship between the water ratio in a hydrate and the enthalpy of hydration, and my results showed a correlation, but an anomaly for calcium chloride. My results were:

```
Sodium carbonate monohydrate: 10.03 kJ
Calcium chloride dihydrate: -19.51 kJ
Sodium acetate trihydrate: 28.98 kJ
Sodium thiosulfate pentahydrate: 47.37 kJ
Sodium sulfate decahydrate: 66.32 kJ
```

I have tried researching about what makes calcium chloride dihydrate unique, but I can't seem to find anything. And this is not a random error, as each of these salt compounds had 3 trials each, with consistent results.

Comment: In this group, it is unique for two reasons. It is the only species with calcium cations, and the only species with chloride anions.

Comment: Try also different hydrates of the same compound, like anhydrous, dihydrate and hexahydrate of calcium chloride.( Other hydrates exist, but are less common ).

Answer (score 3):

The heats of hydration of your salts, plus some others, can be obtained by subtracting the heat of formation of the anhydrous from the heat of formation of the hydrated salt, using the numerical values from the Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, 43rd Ed., 1961, pages 1807 - 1831. The so obtained values are rather different from yours, but the tendency is the same. Here are the obtained molar heats of hydration, divided by the number of water molecules. They are strangely similar.

\begin{array}{lrl}
\text{Compound}      & E /\pu{kJ (mol \ce{H2O})-1}\\\hline
\ce{Na2CO3.H2O}      & 295.3\\
\ce{Na2CO3.10H2O}    & 295.3\\
\ce{NaCH3COO.3H2O}   & 297.6\\
\ce{Na2SO4.10H2O}    & 294.3\\
\ce{Na2S.{4.5}H2O}   & 305.0\\
\ce{Na2S.5H2O}       & 304.6\\
\ce{Na2S.9H2O}       & 301.1\\
\ce{Na2S2O3.5H2O}    & 297.2\\
\ce{Ca(NO3)2.4H2O}   & 297.7\\
\ce{Ca(CH3COO)2.H2O} & 291.2\\
\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}      & 179.6  & (!)\\
\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}      & 301.8
\end{array}

It is immediately clear that the heat of hydration of one molecule $\ce{H2O}$ in these compounds is $\pu{300\pm10 kJ (mol \ce{H2O})-1}$. But there is one odd exception: $\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}$. Has anybody an explanation?

Comment: Try https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/4727#4727

Comment: That is hardly an answer!

Comment: @Mithoron. I agree : it is not an answer. But I had not enough room in the "Comment" section" to insert my text and its numerous numerical values.

Comment: This is much better suited as an edit to the question. I'm sure op will appreciate this, too.

Comment: Maybe make it CW for others to put it into shape?

Comment: Am I allowed to add all my text and numerical values to Shkadov's demand ? And what is CW ?

Comment: @Maurice This is very helpful, thank you! Do you have an online source that states that the heats of hydration is equal to the differences in the heats of formation? I've tried researching it but have had no luck so far.

Comment: @shkadov. If I copy my text with numerical values and insert it in your first demand, there would be an important discrepancy between your values and mine, which is to be avoided. My values are much greater than yours. So what ?

Comment: @Maurice CW=Community Wiki. Its essentially a way of giving up ownership of post so that other users can freely edit and each receives credit (though no further rep will is earned once it is converted)

Comment: I have tried fixing up the table with MathJax (there are markdown tables now, but it was "easier" for me this way). I'd like to reiterate, this shouldn't be an answer. I see no problem with adding this to the original question though. Maybe this would have improved this whole post, leading to it to be reopened and maybe attract an answer then. In general, if you need help with the site (be it MathJax or otherwise), please ask on [meta].